# nginx not setting expires headers on Rails static assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I can't seem to get nginx to set expires headers on my static assets in my Rails app.

My app is deployed using Phusion Passenger & nginx.

Below is the related section of my nginx config file

```
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name my.domain.tld;
        root /home/deploy/my.domain.tld/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        access_log off;

        location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jp?g|png)\?[0-9]+$ {
                expires max;
                break;
        }

        if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
        }
}
```

I'm not sure why its not setting expires headers on my static assets ( e.g. /images/foo.png?123456 )

I'm not sure if it has something to do with passenger or if my location regexp just isnt catching it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I ended up finding the solution.  My regexp was a bit off, as I wasn't taking into account the possibility that the ?timestamp didn't exist.

This regexp worked for me.

```
location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jp?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
```

Comment: This is misleading. location will not match the query parameter, so in reality this matches /all/ image, css, js assets in the list, regardless of the cache busting query parameter. This is undesirable for many people.

Answer (score 10):

Just wanted to point out that making the timestamp optional is a bad idea – if it's not included, then setting `expires max` is wrong as there would be no way of refreshing the file.

Also, the `location` directive in Nginx can't see the query string, so the solution posted here never matches the 'optional' timestamp.

A proper solution (ie one that sends the maximum expires only when the file was requested with a timestamp) would be:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg)$ {
  if ($query_string ~ "^[0-9]+$") {
    expires max;
    break;
  }
}
```

If the timestamp is not specified, then you rely on `Last-Modified` and `ETag`, which are handled automatically by Nginx.

Comment: I removed the `if` since any assets referenced by CSS would not have the timestamp.

Comment: See the first paragraph of my response on why that's a really bad idea. You should be appending timestamps to your assets referenced from your CSS. For example: https://github.com/djanowski/collage/blob/master/lib/collage.rb#L135-142

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to use "break" directive, but access_log off; will be useful:

```
  location ~* \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|css|js|swf|ico)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
      access_log off;
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
```

you can see full config file at github: https://gist.github.com/711913

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
location ~* ^.*\.(ico|css|js|gif|jp?g|png)\?[0-9]+$ {
```

Also read [how Nginx evaluates location](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#location). Are you sure you don't have any other  string `location` in your config file that matches your static resources before your regexp `location` does?

BTW, consider using [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#try_files) instead of `if (-f $document_root/...)`.

Comment: no, that is my current config file.  there are no other location directives.

I'll try your regexp and see if it sets the headers.

Also, I'm not sure why you recommend using try_files instead of the -f flag.  Why / how is try_files and improvement in this case?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but Igor (the author) always recommends using try_files when people ask about rewrites on Nginx mailing list. The "if (-f ...)" directive may be parsed slower, but I've never made any experiment to try that.